# Is the Islamic marriage contract (Katb el-Kitab) considered a Prenup type contract in the Islamic world?

Tags: sunni, nikah, hanafi

Can or Is the marriage contract in Islam considered a prenuptial agreement?

For example, if in the contract it does not include any details on what will happen in a divorce situation other than the dowry belonging to the female, can such a contract be considered a pre-nup?

Answer (score 1):

A marriage contract is a true contract with all that entails. It is not unheard of for monetary considerations to be part of the marriage contract. A clause called *mo'akher assidaq* (loosely translated as dowry post payment) is very common, which dictates an additional sum of money to be paid to the woman in the event of a divorce.